# ssis dbTimeStamp display blank

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a Date output column in ssis package which length="0" and dataType="dbTimeStamp".

```
 <outputColumn id="20" name="ChangeDate" description="" lineageId="20" precision="0" scale="0" length="0" dataType="dbTimeStamp" codePage="0" sortKeyPosition="0" comparisonFlags="0" specialFlags="0" errorOrTruncationOperation="Conversion" errorRowDisposition="FailComponent" truncationRowDisposition="FailComponent" externalMetadataColumnId="19" mappedColumnId="0"/>
```

When I am trying to run below query via sssis the it is giving the error:

```
SELECT
    'No activity to report' as 'DeviceHostName'
    ,'' as [ChangeDate]
    ,'' as 'AffectedAccount'
    ,'' as [Message]
    ,'' as [OriginalValue]
    ,'' as [NewValue]
    ,'' as 'AttackerUserName'
```

Error:

> Error: 2018-03-30 00:15:08.36     Code: 0xC020901C     Source: Data Flow Task OLE DB Source [1]     Description: There was an error with output column "ChangeDate" (20) on output "OLE DB Source Output" (11). The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".  End Error  Error: 2018-03-30 00:15:08.36     Code: 0xC0209029     Source: Data Flow Task OLE DB Source [1]     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "output column "ChangeDate" (20)" failed because error code 0xC0209072 occurred, and the error row disposition on "output column "ChangeDate" (20)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.  End Error  Error: 2018-03-30 00:15:08.36     Code: 0xC0047038     Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "OLE DB Source" (1) returned error code 0xC0209029.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  12:15:01 AM  Finished: 12:15:08 AM  Elapsed:  7.281 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

What should I write in the query to correct this.

Comment: What was the error before that one? That message just tells us that the reason the task stopped was due to an error (and says for you to check the prior error messages `There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure`); you haven't actually provided said error.

Comment: I have edited the post with complete error. Please have a look

Comment: Check Udai's answer. Replace the empty string (`''`) with a `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Anurag: Please can you use 
NULL as [ChangeDate]
instead of
'' as [ChangeDate]

The issue you are facing seems to be because '' or blank string is not getting converted to the proper datatype.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have rights to add comments yet. Hence using Answer to provide a response.

Comment: Doing a `CONVERT(DATETIME, NULL)` would be best.

Comment: Actually this result will be printed on a text file and NULL should not be displayed over there therefore I kept it blank. Is there any way I can replace NULL with blank?

Comment: NULL from a datetime column will be rendered as empty when written as text.